# Generate bidirectional bar chart in matplotlib with variables in center of chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have this dataframe:

```
variable        level   margins_fluid   margins_vp
0   volfluid    1L         0.718          0.690
1   volfluid    2L         0.501          0.808
2   volfluid    5L         0.181          0.920
3   MAP         64         0.434          0.647
4   MAP         58         0.477          0.854
5   MAP         52         0.489          0.904
6   Exam       dry         0.668          0.713
7   exam     euvolemic     0.475          0.798
8   exam       wet         0.262          0.893
9   pmh        COPD        0.506          0.804
10  pmh       Kidney       0.441          0.778
11  pmh         HF         0.450          0.832
12  Case    1 (PIV)        0.435          0.802
13  Case    2 (CVC)        0.497          0.809
```

And I want to build a bi-directional bar chart that looks like the left-most figure in this drawing:

[image]

Where the levels of each variable are listed vertically along the center, and the margins for each are represented as percentages moving away from the center. I have gotten close with the below but not quite there yet:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

font_color = '#525252'
hfont = {'fontname':'Calibri'}
facecolor = '#eaeaf2'
index = fluid_vp_1_2.index
column0 = fluid_vp_1_2['margins_fluid']
column1 = fluid_vp_1_2['margins_vp']
title0 = 'Fluids'
title1 = 'Vasopressors'

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5), facecolor=facecolor, ncols=2, sharey=True)
fig.tight_layout()
axes[0].barh(index, column0, align='center', color='dimgray', zorder=10)
axes[0].set_title(title0, fontsize=18, pad=15, color='black', **hfont)
axes[1].barh(index, column1, align='center', color='lightgray', zorder=10)
axes[1].set_title(title1, fontsize=18, pad=15, color='black', **hfont)
# If you have positive numbers and want to invert the x-axis of the left plot
axes[0].invert_xaxis() 

# To show data from highest to lowest
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

axes[0].set_yticks([])
axes[1].set_yticks([])
```

[image]

But I don't know how to get the variables and their levels to show up in the center of the two graphs. I also need to convert the x-axis to percentages.

Comment: Have you considered using plotly?

Comment: I haven't but maybe it would be a good choice for this?

Comment: Whatever library is going to help me generate a visualization as close to the drawing as possible.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, do you want something like this?

```
font_color = '#525252'
hfont = {'fontname':'Calibri'}
facecolor = '#eaeaf2'
index = yticks
column0 = fluid_vp_1_2['margins_fluid']
column1 = fluid_vp_1_2['margins_vp']
title0 = 'Fluids'
title1 = 'Vasopressors'

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8), facecolor=facecolor, ncols=2, sharey=False)
fig.tight_layout(pad=5)
axes[0].barh(index, column0, align='center', color='dimgray', zorder=10)
axes[0].set_title(title0, fontsize=18, pad=15, color='black', **hfont)
axes[1].barh(index, column1, align='center', color='lightgray', zorder=10)
axes[1].set_title(title1, fontsize=18, pad=15, color='black', **hfont)
# If you have positive numbers and want to invert the x-axis of the left plot
axes[0].invert_xaxis() 

# To show data from highest to lowest
#plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

axes[0].set_yticklabels([])
axes[0].yaxis.tick_right()
axes[1].get_yticks()
yax = axes[1].get_yaxis()
pad = max(T.label1.get_window_extent().width for T in yax.majorTicks)
yax.set_tick_params(pad=pad)

axes[0].set_xticklabels([f'{x:,.2%}' for x in axes[0].get_xticks()]);
axes[1].set_xticklabels([f'{x:,.2%}' for x in axes[1].get_xticks()]);

axes[0].invert_yaxis()
axes[1].invert_yaxis()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Close, but I don't need the variable names to be duplicated 3x. I just need them each once, so for example We would have `Case` and then `1 (PIV)` and `2 (CVC)` and or `Exam` then `dry`, `euvolemic`, and `wet`. Also I'd like it in the same order as the drawing.

Comment: Ah, was wondering if you could update your solution to account for those changes?

Comment: Also, like the drawing, I would like to add some space in between each individual variable.

Comment: @hulio_entredas you should at least upvote the answer.

Comment: For sure, just did. It's a great start.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exaxtly what you asked for but is just a way to show how plotly works in this case.

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

data = {'variable': {0: 'volfluid',
  1: 'volfluid',
  2: 'volfluid',
  3: 'MAP',
  4: 'MAP',
  5: 'MAP',
  6: 'Exam',
  7: 'exam',
  8: 'exam',
  9: 'pmh',
  10: 'pmh',
  11: 'pmh',
  12: 'Case',
  13: 'Case'},
 'level': {0: '1L',
  1: '2L',
  2: '5L',
  3: '64',
  4: '58',
  5: '52',
  6: 'dry',
  7: 'euvolemic',
  8: 'wet',
  9: 'COPD',
  10: 'Kidney',
  11: 'HF',
  12: '1 (PIV)',
  13: '2 (CVC)'},
 'margins_fluid': {0: 0.718,
  1: 0.501,
  2: 0.181,
  3: 0.434,
  4: 0.477,
  5: 0.489,
  6: 0.668,
  7: 0.475,
  8: 0.262,
  9: 0.506,
  10: 0.441,
  11: 0.45,
  12: 0.435,
  13: 0.497},
 'margins_vp': {0: 0.69,
  1: 0.808,
  2: 0.92,
  3: 0.647,
  4: 0.854,
  5: 0.904,
  6: 0.713,
  7: 0.798,
  8: 0.893,
  9: 0.804,
  10: 0.778,
  11: 0.832,
  12: 0.802,
  13: 0.809}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

## Plot

Here I added commens inside the code

```py
# create subplots
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1,
    cols=2,
    # specs=[[{}, {}]],
    # shared_xaxes=False,
    shared_yaxes=True,
    horizontal_spacing=0)

fig.append_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=df['margins_fluid'],
        y=[df['variable'], df["level"]], # here you want the two levels
        text=df["margins_fluid"].map(lambda x:f'{x*100:.2f}%'), # text as percentage
        textposition='inside', 
        orientation='h', 
        width=0.7, # space between bars
        showlegend=False, 
        marker_color='dimgray',), 
        1, 1) # 1,1 represents row 1 column 1 in the plot grid

fig.append_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=df['margins_vp'],
        y=[df['variable'], df["level"]],
        text=df["margins_vp"],
        textposition='inside',
        texttemplate="%{x:.4p}",# text as percentage
        orientation='h', 
        width=0.7, # space between bars
        showlegend=False,
        marker_color='lightgray'), 
        1, 2) # 1,2 represents row 1 column 2 in the plot grid

fig.update_xaxes(
    showticklabels=False,
    tickformat=',.0%', # if you want ticks you should comment the line above
    title_text="<b>Fluid</b>",# html bold
    row=1,
    col=1,
    autorange='reversed'
)
fig.update_xaxes(
    showticklabels=False,
    title_text="<b>Vasopressor</b>",# html bold
    row=1,
    col=2)

fig.update_layout(
    title_text="<b>Title</b>",# html bold
    barmode="group", # stacked or grouped bar
    width=900, 
    height=700,
    title_x=0.5,
    xaxis1={'side': 'top'},
    xaxis2={'side': 'top'},
    paper_bgcolor='#eaeaf2',
    plot_bgcolor='white',
    # custom padding
    margin=dict(l=20,
                r=20, 
                #t=20,
                b=20),
    # xaxis1_range=[0, 1],
    # xaxis2_range=[0, 1],
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I may end up using something like this. Do you think it would be possible to make it look like this [example](https://i.ibb.co/Qrty1DW/bidirectional-bar-chart.png)? Where the x-axis is labeled as percentage? I would still want it to have the same order of variables and variable headers shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76078462/19980284).

Comment: Hi @hulio_entredas, yes it's possible. Just let me have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate it. I was in the process of asking a new question, so I will link it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76101455/19980284) if you would like to respond there.