# y-ticks between sublopts in Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76073586/generate-bidirectional-bar-chart-in-matplotlib-with-variables-in-center-of-chart/76076468?noredirect=1#comment134210758_76076468) question and I was wondering if there is a way to put the y-ticks and names between 2 subplots.

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

data = {'variable': {0: 'Case', 1: 'Exam', 2: 'History', 3: 'MAP', 4: 'Volume'},
 'margins_fluid': {0: 0.497, 1: 0.668, 2: 0.506, 3: 0.489, 4: 0.718},
 'margins_vp': {0: 0.809, 1: 0.893, 2: 0.832, 3: 0.904, 4: 0.92}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

## Plot

```py
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1,
    cols=2,
    shared_xaxes=False,
    shared_yaxes=True,
    horizontal_spacing=0,
    subplot_titles=['<b>Fluid</b>', '<b>Vasopressor</b>'])

fig.append_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=df['margins_fluid'],
        y=df['variable'], 
        text=df["margins_fluid"], 
        textposition='inside',
        texttemplate="%{x:.4p}",
        orientation='h', 
        width=0.7, # space between bars 
        showlegend=False, ), 
        1, 1) # 1,1 represents row 1 column 1 in the plot grid

fig.append_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=df['margins_vp'],
        y=df['variable'], 
        text=df["margins_vp"],
        textposition='inside',
        texttemplate="%{x:.4p}",
        orientation='h', 
        width=0.7, 
        showlegend=False), 
        1, 2) # 1,2 represents row 1 column 2 in the plot grid

fig.update_xaxes(
    tickformat=',.0%', 
    row=1,
    col=1,
    autorange='reversed',)
fig.update_xaxes(
    tickformat=',.0%', 
    row=1,
    col=2)

fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Title",
    barmode="group",
    width=800, 
    height=700,
    title_x=0.5,
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the yaxis for the first plot to the right hand side, and therefore in-between the two.

You would only need to add the following line of code.

```
fig.update_layout({'yaxis1': {'side': 'right'}})
```

However, you would also need to widen the `horizontal_spacing` between the two plots to allow for it to fit. This is currently set to 0 in your code.